# Ajax Request returns with an empty response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, apache

I've got the follow situation:

On my local server I made this call

*File: history.js*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button[data-pid]').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({ pch_id: $(this).data('pid') }),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: REPAIR_BROKEN_BANNER_URL
        }).done(function(data) {

            $('#fix-broken-banner-text').text(data.message);

            if (!data.error) {
                $('#fix-broken-banner-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
                    window.location.href = window.location.href;
                });
            }

            $('#fix-broken-banner-modal').modal('show');

        }).fail(function() {
            $('#fix-broken-banner-text').text(REPAIR_BROKEN_ERR_GENERIC);
            $('#fix-broken-banner-modal').modal('show');
        });
    });
});
```

*Page inclusion*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/history.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var REPAIR_BROKEN_BANNER_URL = '/admin/banners/repair-broken-banner/';
    var REPAIR_BROKEN_ERR_GENERIC = 'Unable to perform the action';
</script>
```

The server responds always with a JSON, still it happened an error.

The issue is on the production server. (Production server is a virtual server with Debian). When the ajax call the action, it gets always a blank response, with the follow headers:

**Request URL:** http://debug.xxxxxxx.xxx/admin/banners/repair-broken-banner/

**Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.**

- Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
- Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
- Origin:http://debug.xxxxxxx.xxx
- Referer:http://debug.xxxxxxx.xxx/admin/banners/history-list
- User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
- (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
- X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data

- pch_id:697f1eaa2fc691a9a7d22d315f7ed8c966febe8ec2c57c1c7a867897f6431dfb8b596ef9dd8f2394c875c638496f7ec9

I thought it could be a php error, but If I write a message and die at the first script call, the page remains blank. In the apache access logs there's no trace of the call.
I've tried this call in firefox and it doesn't appear into the XHR tab, as though the call it's not performed.

**EDIT:** Javascript part is complete

Comment: Are you using internet explorer? Or a server that doesn't allow properly AJAX request?

Comment: Looks like you asking to send JSON data but { pch_id: $(this).data('pid') },does not look like json try using data:JSON.stringify({ pch_id: $(this).data('pid') )

Comment: I tested it on Google Chrome and on Firefox. I use Windows 7

Comment: The best way to debug this type of thing is using fiddler. You can see all the requests and what data is returned.

http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Comment: It also looks like Abhik is right. What does your file look like that's trying to catch the call?

Comment: Why not try .fail(function(data) { console.log( data ); } at least you will have a better idea of what is being returned.

Comment: I use the JSON.stringify function but the result is the same. Now I try to use telerik to see the request and gets more data. But I don't think it's a javascript errors, because I have no trace of the call in the Apache access.log

Comment: I install telerik and it seems that the browser doesn't send the request. I performed `console.log(data);` and it gives me readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"

Comment: There is no case where `data` in a success callback (or .done) should give that. Can you give us the actual code you are using?

Comment: I write all javascript code. The code works on development server (that is a Virtual Machine bridged to the network). The servers configurations are similar. I think that could be a kind of permission on the Ajax request, eg. domains, but It's an assumption.

Comment: The magic happens: Only On Internet Explorer 10 works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using Adblock plus.
It has nothing to do with the Javascript, and more to do with the URL itself.

You have the word banners in the URL.
Request URL: http://debug.xxxxxxx.xxx/admin/**banners**/repair-broken-banner/

Disable Adblock plus for your site, and it should work flawlessly.

Comment: Sorry for the late, but the project is dead. The request works correctly with the change. Thanks